# Proceed button works correctly,and the same way implemented back button first jumps and then does animation, if does at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, jquery-animate, back

Here is the implementation of the back button. I really don't know how to resolve this issue.

```
$("#back").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var string = $("section:not(.hidden)").attr("id");
    var num = string.charAt(10);
    $("#portfolio_" + (num-1)).removeClass("hidden");
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: ($("#portfolio_" + (num-1)).offset().top)
    }, 1250, 'easeInOutExpo');
    setTimeout(function(){$("#portfolio_" + (num)).addClass("hidden")}, 2500);
});
```

Comment: Can you specify your question?  What is exaclty happening and what should it do?

Comment: It should return to previous section, and do animation while doing that. But, when it's like this, it jumps on previous section after this line:     

    $("#portfolio_" + (num-1)).removeClass("hidden");

and then it doesn't animate. It should slide back with animation. I hope i explained it well? :)

Comment: I feel there is some **`error`**. You have `event.preventDefault();` but you never included `event` in your `function` like `.click(function(event){`. Is that typo?

Comment: post some dummy `html` too if possible to create problem workaround

Comment: No, it doesn't change when i type event. I will try to make some dummy HTML, it is a bit complicated with all this. Thank you for answers.